# Pass XML to a Flex application

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I read that the ways to pass data to a Flex application are flashvars and URL fragments. However, it seems both are appropriate only for simple data. What if I want to pass some (dynamic) XML data to Flex? Which way is better for this case? Or is there another way altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a GET response and passing it in the query string. I know it's ugly, but I didn't find any other way...

Answer (score 2):

Just load your XML data from a server at runtime.  For XML, I would use either a [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) or an [HTTPService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/mxml/HTTPService.html) call.

Comment: The problem is that I have an HTML page which has the XML data, and it has to navigate to the HTML page containing the Flex application and pass it the XML, so I can't retrieve the data from a server.

Comment: You realize all HTML pages must reside on a server?  IT is part of the paradigm of the web.  If you have an HTML page w/ XML on it; you can load that page using URLRequest / URLLoader and parse your XML data that way.